# log concavity and the equivalent inequalities

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

A finite sequence of positive integers $a_0, a_1, \dots, a_n$ is said to be logarithmically concave if $$a_i^2 \ge a_{i-1} a_{i+1}$$
for all $1 \le i \le n-1$.

Now consider the set of inequalities:
$$a_ia_j \ge a_h a_k$$
for $0 \le h \le i \le j \le k \le n$ and $h + k = i + j$.

How to prove the equivalence of the two sets of inequalities given above.

Kindly share your thoughts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the forward direction, apply induction to $a_i a_j \geq a_{i - 1} a_{j + 1}$ for $0 < i \leq j < n$.

The latter, for $0 < i < j < n$, follows from
$$\prod_{k = i}^{j} a^2_k \geq \prod_{k = i}^{j} a_{k - 1} a_{k + 1} = a_{i - 1} \left(a_i a_j \prod_{k = i + 1}^{j - 1}a^2_k \right) a_{j + 1}$$
(where the product of zero terms is considered to be $1$ - just divide both sides by the parenthesized expression). The other direction of the equivalence is just taking a particular case.

**UPDATE.** The induction application mentioned above produces $a_i a_j \geq a_{i - d} a_{j + d}$ for $0 \leq d \leq i \leq j \leq n - d$, the induction being on $d$. This is exactly what is needed: if $0 \leq h \leq i \leq j \leq k \leq n$ and $h + k = i + j$, then $h = i - d$ and $k = j + d$ with $d = i - h$.

Comment: dividing both sides by the parenthesized expression giving me $a_j^2 \ge a_{i-1}a_{j+1}$. From this how to deduce the required inequalities. Also where we are using $h + k = i + j$. Can you please give a little more elaborate answer. Also I dont understand what you mean by applying induction the inequality. Kindly clarify. Thank you.

Comment: For example, how to prove $a_j^2 \ge a_{i-1}a_{j+1} \ge a_{i-2}a_{j+2}$ ?

Comment: No, it gives $a_i a_j \geq a_{i - 1} a_{j + 1}$, check carefully. For the induction matter - OK, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Sorry. you are right. I am getting $a_i a_j \ge a_{i-1}a_{j+1}$. Kindly edit the induction part. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is sufficient. I have got it from this. Thanks a lot for the nice answer.